# Instantiate IUnitOfWork for each ViewModels in WPF/Prism app

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container, unit-of-work, lifetime

I have lots of repositories like this:

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public PersonRepository(IUnitOfWork instance)
    {
        _unitOfWork = instance;
    }

    //Remove, Get methods...
    public void Add(Person p)
    {
        _unitOfWork.Context.People.Add(p);
    }
}
```

and Unit of work class like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public UnitOfWork(){ }

    private readonly HezarehContext _context = new HezarehContext();
    public HezarehContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return _context;
        }
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Database.Initialize(false);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now i want each time my ViewModels gets resolved, a new `IUnitOfWork` instantiated. Most of my ViewModels are like this:

```
public class PeopleMainViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    // both of repositories must have same instance of IUnitOfWork
    private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetService<IPersonRepository>();
    private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetService<ICategoryRepository>();

    public PeopleMainViewModel()
    {
        InitializeView();
    }

    // add, edit, remove commands ...
}
```

ViewModels always gets resolved using Unity Container like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>();
// resolve in InjectionProperty...
Container.RegisterType<Object, PeopleMainView>("PeopleMainView", new InjectionProperty(PeopleMainView.DataContextProperty.Name, Container.Resolve<PeopleMainViewModel>();
```

And my question is, **How** and **Where** i Register my `ViewModel`s and `IUnitOfWork` to have `IUnitOfWork` instance for each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
There is another solution [here in unity.codeplex discussions](http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/391225).

I finally found a solution.
There is a feature in `Unity` container that let you pass parameters while resolving a `Type`. by changing constructor of ViewModels to this:

```
public class PeopleMainViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository = null;
    private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository = null;

    public PeopleMainViewModel(IUnityContainer container, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        // now both of repositories have same instance of IUnitOfWork
        _personRepository = container.Resolve<IPersonRepository>(new ParameterOverride("unitOfWork", unitOfWork));
        _categoryRepository = container.Resolve<ICategoryRepository>(new ParameterOverride("unitOfWork", unitOfWork));
        InitializeView();
    }

    // add, edit, remove commands ...
}
```

problem solved. now `_personReposiotry` and `_categoryRepository` have reference to same instance of `unitOfWork`.

Comment: You are passing the container around like a service locator. this is not correct use of DI and containers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, just register your `IUnitOfWork` the same way (and same place) you register the repository in your above example.  You don't need to register your ViewModels based on your current design since you aren't using an Interface.

```
Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

And continue to have your repositories accept the `IUnitOfWork` in the constructor.  This will allow Unity to use constructor injection to provide a new instance of `IUnitOfWork` each time it resolves a repository.  By default, you'll get a new instance of the `IUnitOfWork` each time.  If you'd like to have a singleton `IUnitOfWork`, you would have to say so when you register the `IUnitOfWork` like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

If you want to read up on Lifetime Managers, you can do so [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647854.aspx).

I would also recommend changing your ViewModels to take the repositories in as Constructor Parameters, like this if you are going to Resolve them (so Unity will do the work without you referencing the `ServiceLocator` directly)

```
public PeopleMainViewModel(IPersonRepository personRepo, ICategoryRepository categoryRepo)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer,but as I asked, I want each time a ViewModel instantiated, a new IUnitOfWork instantiated, NOT for each REPOSITORY! I mean, all repositories in a ViewModel must have same instance of IUnitOfWork object.

Comment: Then have the ViewModel take an instance of the IUnitOfWork in the constructor and pass it into all the Repositories that are used in that ViewModel.

Comment: Pass it manually? I there any way Unity container do it for me?

Comment: If you add the IUnitOfWork as a parameter of the ViewModel's constructor, and you have registered IUnitOfWork with the container, and you are resolving the ViewModel through the container, then the container will take care of populating the constructor parameter (IUnitOfWork) for you.  This is a form of dependency injection called Constructor Injection.